# obtain a lower bound for Probability of x less than or equal 275 and greater than or equal 225

Tags: probability, statistics

Let x denote the number of heads in n tosses of a fair coin.use chebyshev`s inequality to obtain a lower bound for Probability of x less than or equal $275$ and greater than or equal $225$.

Could you explain to me how can we find that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use two sided chebyshev's inequality which says
\begin{align}
P(a \leq X \leq b)\geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2 + (\mu-(\frac{a+b}{2}))^2}{\frac{(b-a)}{2}^2}
\end{align}
Now we know that the distribution of random variable $X$, which denotes the $n$ tosses of coins is Binomial distribution with mean $\mu=np$, and variance $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$. If we assume fair coin so that $p=1/2$, then the problem at hand is
\begin{align}
P(225<X<275)\geq 1- \frac{n/4 +(n/2-250)^2}{625}
\end{align}
after substituting $a=225$, $b=275$ and $p=1/2$

(The reference for above formula is http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jsbm/courses/311/cheby.pdf)